# Javascript turn the function off with a button

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to make a simple game, I have made a function the increases the points for the player automatically. The function does not run at the start but when you press a button it runs. My only problem is, however getting a button to turn it off.

My html

```
<button onclick="autoMake(); automake = 1;">Automake Hotdogs - On</button>
<button onclick="automake = 0;">Automake Hotdogs - Off</button>
```

My Javascript

```
var auto = 1;
var automake = 0;
function autoMake() {
    if (automake === 1) {
        if (bread >= automake) {
            if (hotdog >= automake) {
                if (sauce >= automake) {
                    (function loop(timer) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            assembleClick(auto);
                            loop(100);
                        }, timer)
                    })(100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[edit] changed to the right comparison thing. though clicking the stop button does not work still

Comment: The if statement assigns your automake variable to the value 1, instead of checking whether it is equal to 1. You need `automake === 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine those `if` statements with the [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) (`&&`):

```
function autoMake() {
    if (automake === 1 && bread >= automake && hotdog >= automake && sauce >= automake) {
        (function loop(timer) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (automake === 1){
                    assembleClick(auto);
                    loop(100);
                }
            }, timer)
        })(100)
    }
};
```

Notice that I changed `automake = 1` to `automake === 1`.

`=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators), `===` is an (equality) [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators).

This should properly check if `automake` equals `1`.

Comment: yes it has made a made a change, although the off button doesn't stop the function